# having issues using custom exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw

I have a form program I wrote in Visual Studio 2010. In the program I wrote new exceptions file called *LibraryGeneralExceptions.cs*

```
namespace Database
{
    public class LibraryGeneralExceptions : Exception
    {
        public LibraryGeneralExceptions()
        {
        }

        public void ItemInsertError()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item Insert Error", "Error");
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

under the same namespace I have

```
public void ItemInsert(string name,string creator,string publishing,string itemType,string genere, string year)
{
    ...
    if (errorMsg.Length != 0)
    {
       throw new ItemInsertError();
        MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "error");
    }
```

under another namespace that uses Database and calls for functions from Database i'm trying to set up a `try-catch` to catch exceptions that database will make using LibraryGeneralExceptions, but I cannot seem to make it work for some reason.

Comment: Here's my suggestion: forget about exceptions and go back to learn the basics of C#. You don't even know how to create a class with a constructor.

Comment: It is also good to write comments in English, for example English is not my first language, but I write comments only in English, it is much easier for other people to understand what is happening without using any translators.

Comment: @John, while you may be right it's always good to assist and guide one into the right direction with [constructive criticism](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) to obtain the knowledge to learn, even if it's just providing a link to the information. [Refer the FAQ on etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: @Brett: Pardon me, but that _was_ constructive criticism. He's not going to get far with custom classes until he solidifies his understanding of the foundations. Showing him anything about exceptions when he can't create a simple class is counterproductive and not helping where he needs the help. Let him ask a question about constructors, and I'll answer it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lakovl it seems you may be misunderstanding how exceptions work in C#. One point of reference you may like to start reading is the [MSDN article on exceptions and exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx), please also review the child sections.

When an exception is thrown it is a point at where a fault occurred, when caught it is being handled, and when re-thrown via a wrapped exception it is a reference that you tried to resolve a fault and couldn't or were simply catching to log.

To be analogous imagine you have a chain of people, an ice-cream truck has arrived and one person asks someone to go and buy them an ice-cream, they run off to the truck only to find that the original person didn't give them enough money. The ice-cream vendor throws an exception `InsufficientFundsException` which is caught and re-thrown by the colleague. Now, if the collegue is generous enough they may wish to add finding for them, though if they also don't have funds they will re-throw the exception by wrapping it up. Finally they run back to the originator (this is called bubbling up) which they may then resolve or abandon.

Now lets examine what you've done with your exception. What you've tried to do is create an exception type `LibraryGeneralExceptions` which is fine (except for the plural form, drop the `s`) though you have created a method `ItemInsertError` which in your code are treating it as if it is an exception of its own. So let's try fix your problem.

Firstly it looks as though you intended to use `LibraryGeneralExceptions` as a sub-namespace and `ItemInsertError` is meant to be an exception, so here is a correct implementation:

```
namespace Database {
    public class ItemInsertError : Exception {
        public ItemInsertError() : base() {}
        public void ItemInsertError(string message) : base(message) {}
    }
}
```

Now let's examine your insert method, the first thing wrong is you're handling the exception and alerting the user at the same time, instead, let's just handle the exception.

```
public void ItemInsert(string name,
                       string creator,
                       string publishing,
                       string itemType,
                       string genre,
                       string year) {
    // ...
    if (errorMsg.Length != 0) {
       throw new ItemInsertError(errorMsg);
    }
}
```

So now when we invoke the `ItemInsert` method we will then handle exceptions in that piece of code.

```
try {
    ItemInsert("name", "creator", "publishing", "itemType", "genre", 2012);
} catch (ItemInsertError ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(
        ex.Message, "Error during insert",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

From this your user will now have feedback of what went wrong, your client code can now try to recover as in where my prior example decides if we can find more funds or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to throw a `ItemInsertError`, you need a `ItemInsertError` class that derives from `System.Exception`:

```
public class ItemInsertError : Exception
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong on so many levels, I don't know where to start. I would recommend reading the MSDN documentation on exception handling and custom exceptions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab.aspx

Visual Studio also provides a snippet for templating custom exceptions in the format that follows best practices.

See http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSExceptionSnippet.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You want to throw a new `LibraryGeneralExceptions`, not a method inside your exception.  You don't throw the methods within an exception class - you're actually throwing an instance of the exception class itself.  This allows you to encapsulate some other information for the caller that could be helpful (such as the state of the system when thrown, what data was passed in that caused the exception, etc.).

For an immediate fix, you should call the logic from your constructor for `LibraryGeneralExceptions`.

```
namespace Database
{
    public class LibraryGeneralExceptions : Exception
    {
        public LibraryGeneralExceptions()
        {
          ItemInsertError();
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you really want different behaviors (one for an `ItemInsertError` and maybe another for a `NetworkTimeoutError`), you'd probably want to create different `Exception` classes for those.

Answer (score 0):

An exception is an instance of the `System.Exception` class, or a derived class. You need to derive your custom exception class from `System.Exception`:

```
namespace LibraryExceptions {
    public class InsertError : Exception  {

    }
}
```

and `throw` a new instance of it.

```
throw new LibraryExceptions.InsertError()
```